# Where it is possible to write the base condition in the recursive methods

Tags: java, recursion

I was reading about recursive methods in java ... I do not undserstand the base condition of the recursive method ... Here are two examples

```
public int weight() {
return weight(root);
}
/ * Returns the weight of the tree where n is the root. * /
private int weight(Node n) {
if (n == null) {
return 0;
} else if (n.left == null) { // då är n.right också null
return n.data;
} else {
return weight(n.left) + weight(n.right);
}
}
```

---

```
public boolean isMobile() {
if (root == null) {
return true;
} else {
return isMobile(root);
}
}
/ * Returns true if the tree where n is the root of a mobile. * /
private boolean isMobile(Node n) {
if (n.left == null) { // då är n.right också null
return true;
} else {
return isMobile(n.left) && isMobile(n.right) &&
weight(n.left) == weight(n.right);
}
}
```

---

My wonder : in the weight() method why do not we do like this :

```
public int weight() {
if (root == null) {
    return 0; 
} else {
    return weight(root);
    }
}
```

As you can see the base condition in the isMobile() method is directly under it but the base condition in the weight() method is under the private method ..
When it is possible to write the base condition of the recursive directly under it or in a separate private method ?

Thanks

EDIT :

```
public int weight() {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0; 
    } else {
        return weight(root);
        }
    }

private int weight(Node n) {
    if (n == null) {
    return 0;
    } else if (n.left == null) { // då är n.right också null
    return n.data;
    } else {
    return weight(n.left) + weight(n.right);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base condition must be in the recursive method. The method `weight()` is not recursive as it is not calling itself. It is calling a recursive method `weight(Node n)` which has and must have base condition.

```
if (n == null) { return 0; }
```

Intention in the `isMobile()` and `isMobile(Node n)` is a bit different. The author probably wanted to check for `root == null` directly in `isMobile()` method to avoid double checks in recursive method but they can be rewritten like this:

```
public boolean isMobile() {
  return isMobile(root);
}

private boolean isMobile(Node n) {
  if ( n == null || n.left == null ) return true;
  return isMobile(n.left) && isMobile(n.right) && weight(n.left) == weight(n.right);
}
```

Again `isMobile(Node n)` is recursive and `isMobile()` is not. The `isMobile` methods now look the same as `weight` methods. In general the rule is that the recursive methods are the ones which call themselves and they must have base condition which will terminate recursion.

Also please note that you do not need to write `else` if you have a return before that. For example:

```
boolean someMethod() {
  if ( something ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
boolean someMethod() {
  if ( something ) {
    // ...
    return true;
  }
  // if something was true then the next piece of code will never get executed
  // if was not true then the next piece of code will always execute

  // ...
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks ,, Mr stjepano ... God bless you ,,, Now I do understand it very well :)

Comment: in isMobile method : what is the meaning of returning `return isMobile(n.left) && isMobile(n.right)`

Comment: `isMobile(n.left)` is recursive call over what I think is left branch of tree and `isMobile(n.right)` recursive call over the right branch of tree. First left is evaluated and if it is true then and only then the right side is evaluated. So basically if left side is false you will avoid recursive calls over the right side.

Answer (score 3):

> in the `weight()` method why do not we do like this : [...]

The simple answer is because parameterless `weight()` overload of the method is not recursive, even though it relies on a recursive implementation that takes `Node` as its parameter. The base condition must be in the recursive method itself, because that is where the decision to stop calling itself must be made.

Despite being overloads of the same name, your two weight methods work together like this:

```
public int nonRecursiveWeight() {
    return recursiveWeight(root);
}
private int recursiveWeight(Node n) {
    ...
}
```

The `nonRecursiveWeight` provides a nice public "front" for the recursive implementation `recursiveWeight`, hiding the node from the API users.

`isMobile` pair of methods follows the same arrangement: you have a recursive implementation, and a non-recursive "front" sharing the same name.

Comment: but even isMobile() method is parameterless

Comment: @CarMar There are two `isMobile` methods - the non-recursive public "front", and a recursive private implementation.

Comment: @CarMar  Yes, it is; it also uses different logic to determine its final value and a check for a null `Node` in the recursive method is not sufficient.

Comment: Is it wrong if I do like this the the nonrecursiveweight : `public int weight() {
if (root == null) {
    return 0; 
} else {
    return weight(root);
    }
}`

Comment: @CarMar The edit at the bottom of your post simply copies the logic that is already present in the recursive code into the non-recursive code. This is not productive, and it is also useless. The code already works 100% correctly, without the additional check.

Comment: @CarMar "Is it wrong?" No, it still works. But as has been mentioned by others, it is not productive. It smells of duplicative logic, which is a smell that all programmers come to hate (or get driven out of the profession).

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant `if (root == null)` in your re-write.

You still have to check in `weight(Node)` since it's recursive–why do it twice?

Comment: I corrected it .. thank you ... but how would you rewrite it as I wanted it .. :)

Comment: please look at my EDIT at the bottom of my post ... Did you mean that as I wrote ?

Comment: @CarMar  Yes. Do you see how you are forced to duplicate logic? *I* don't like duplicating logic, which is why *I* wouldn't write it like that. It's pointless. `isMobile` has different conditions for early termination.

Comment: in isMobile method : what is the meaning of returning `return isMobile(n.left) && isMobile(n.right)`

Comment: @CarMar  ... it's returning the result of the two recursive `isMobile` calls, logically ANDed together. Just like the code says. (With the possible shortcut logic if the left-side is false.)